# How can I set an oracle procedure's parameter default to the result of a select?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

I have an oracle Procedure and I want to set the default parameter to the result of a select statement such as below.

```
procedure foo( startID number : = max(x.id) from xtable x )
```

but the code above is illegal syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an otherwise unvalid value for this meaning, for example NULL:

```
PROCEDURE foo (p_id NUMBER DEFAULT NULL) IS
   l_startID NUMBER := p_id;
BEGIN
   IF p_id IS NULL THEN
      SELECT max(id) INTO l_startID FROM xtable;
   END IF;
   ...
END;
```

If your function/procedure is in a package, you could also [overload](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#i12352) it:

```
PROCEDURE foo (p_id NUMBER)
[...]

PROCEDURE foo IS
   l_startID NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT max(id) INTO l_startID FROM xtable;
   foo(l_startID);
END;
```